# Workflow engine for C/C++

Tags: c++, c, workflow, native, workflow-engine

I am looking for a plain C/C++ workflow engine with support of BPML/BPEL. It should be native code without references to Java or .NET. It may or may not be open source.

Comment: Business process modeling/execution language

Answer (score 3):

In the past I've developed a BPMS framework based on C++ Workflow Engine.

At the moment I've extracted Workflow Engine from the framework and my roadmap is to implement xpdl standard and cross platform (now is only Windows).

You can find [code here](http://criteria.codeplex.com/) and download a Business Process modeler based on Visio.

Let me know your impressions.

Answer (score 0):

There is one base on Microsoft WF it called [Criteria](http://criteria.codeplex.com/) but its low level.